# Kion signifas ‘garnizonta’? Ĉu tajperaro?

Tags: literature

En *Asteriks kaj Kleopatra* (volumo VII) mi trovis sur paĝo 3 la jenan alineon:

> Ni estas en la jaro 50 a.K. La tuta Gaŭlujo estas okupita de la Romianoj. Ĉu la tuta Gaŭlujo? – Absolute ne! Unu vilaĝo de persistemaj gaŭloj ne ĉesas rezisti kontraŭ la entrudiĝintoj. Kaj la vivo ne estas facila al la legianoj ***garnizontaj*** en la fortikaĵoj Kalkanum, Linoleum, Kukum, Cicum…

(Emfazo mia; la originalo estas en nur majusklaj literoj.)

Mi ne povas trovi la vorton *garnizonta* en alia loko; ĝi ne aperas en PIV, ReVo, kaj Tekstaro. De alilingvaj versioj de la komikso mi inferencas, ke la celata signifo estas *garnizonantaj*; el PIV:

> **garnizoni** (ntr) Restadi garnizone.
>
> **garnizon<sup>1</sup>o** ⚔
> **1** Militistaro, gardanta fortikaĵon, urbon, aŭ daŭre loĝanta en ĝi: *restigi*<sup>Z</sup>, *starigi*<sup>Z</sup> *garnizonon*; *resti garnizone en urbo*<sup>Z</sup>; *garnizona urbo*; *urboj, kie staras malgrandaj garnizonoj*<sup>Z</sup>.
> **2** garnizonejo.

Ĉu tio ja estas tajperaro kaj la celata signifo estas *garnizonantaj*, aŭ ĉu mi maltrafis la obskuran ekziston de *garnizontaj*, kiu havas iun alian signifon?

Comment: Ĉu estas aliaj Asteriksaj volumoj en Esperanto? Se jes, oni komparu kun ilin. (Sed eble ili havas saman supozantan tajperaron.)

Comment: Estas aliaj; mi legis la unuan volumon, sed mi mem ne posedas ĝin. Tio ja estas bona ideo; espereble alia persono ĉi tie havas iun por kontroli.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La franca originalo tekstas jene: "Et la vie n'est pas facile pour les garnisons de légionnaires romains...". Do klare temas pri tajperaro, kiel vi prave supozis.